# How to copy file to subfolder in directoy that contains name

Tags: macos, terminal, directory, target

I have a large amount of files (60.000) that are sorted and have an identifying component in the name. These files need to be allocated to different subfolders within a certain folder. Each of the subfolders is named after the identifying component of the file name.
Instead of downloading/drag and dropping all the files that belong into a certain subfolder I would like to use a command in Terminal (Mac) to say "if you find a file with this name, copy to the folder with the same name".

I am currently using this command:

$ cat file.csv | xargs -I [] find /Users/me/where/to/search -type f -name "[]*"  -exec cp {} /Users/me/where/to/copy \;

My question now is, how can I tell Terminal to copy the files to a subfolder that contains the name Terminal is searching for as per file.csv?

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Does `cat file.csv | xargs -I "[]" find /Users/me/where/to/search -type f -name "[]*" -exec cp {} "/Users/me/where/to/copy/[]/" \;` not work? I added quotes since your command didn't work for me without them, but xargs appears to honor the replstr in the -exec portion.

Comment: Although the name in the .csv file, the component of the file searched for, and the directory folder are all spelled the exact same way it says that it cannot find the target folder

Comment: I correct, I adjusted the name of the folder and it worked. Seems like something must have gone wrong with the folder name creation! Thanks a lot @EdmCoff !

Comment: this probably for another thread though: The problem is that when I create the folder names using cat file.txt | xargs mkdir all folders except for the last one have "?" as a suffix. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: That mkdir command seems to work for me. Is it possible your file is uses Windows EOL delimiters or something? Just speculating.

Comment: I've tried with a plain text .txt file and a .csv file (UTF-8) but none of them work. I found however that pressing enter after every line in the .txt file resolves the issue (not however if I press enter at the beginning of the line).